# How to generate random alphabet (vowels only)

Tags: vb.net

**My Current Code**

> Public Class Form1
>
> Dim randomObject As New Random()
>
> ```
> Dim alphaRand As Integer = randomObject.Next(65, 91)
>
>  Dim alpha As String = Me.textAlphabet.Text.ToUpper
>
>     Dim asciicode As Integer = Asc(alpha)
>
>     If asciicode = alphaRand Then
>         Me.lblAlphaResult.Text = "Congratulation! Your guess:  " & textAlphabet.Text & " is correct,you win"
>         Me.cmdAlphaNewGame.Enabled = True
>         Me.cmdAlphaGuess.Enabled = False
>     ElseIf asciicode < alphaRand Then
>         Me.lblAlphaResult.Text = "You guess is too low.Try again"
>     ElseIf asciicode > alphaRand Then
>         Me.lblAlphaResult.Text = "Your guess is too high.Try again"
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```
>
> End Class

****randomObject.Next(65, 91) ' which means it take generate random alpha to A-Z only according to asciicode , what about only vowels ?****

**Can i use something like array 
Dim vowels As String() = {"A", "E", "I", "O", "U"}
then generate the random alphabet from my string 
for me to guess later**

Comment: If 65 to 91 comprises all the letters, it seems clear that the vowels will be 5 numbers within this range. Finding this out (the exact numbers) does not sound too difficult, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

```
Dim vowels As String() = {"A","E","I","O","U"}
Dim i As Int32 = randomObject.Next (0, 5)
Return vowels(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

or just use a string

```
Dim randomObject As New Random
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim vowels As String = "AEIOU"

    Dim vowelpicked As String

    vowelpicked = vowels.Substring(randomObject.Next(vowels.Length), 1)

    Debug.Write(vowelpicked)
End Sub
```